# Add node to Tree Problems

Tags: c, pointers, tree, header, structure

I am having trouble with adding node to my search tree. I have many errors like "comparison between pointer and integer" and " expected char but argument is of type char*". Here is my code:

```
 void addNode(WordTreeNode ** tree, char tok)
 {
   WordTreeNode *temp = NULL;
   if(!(*tree))
   {
      temp = (WordTreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(WordTreeNode));
      temp->leftChild = temp->rightChild = NULL;
      temp->name = tok;
      *tree = temp;
      return;
   }

   if(tok < (*tree)->name)
   {
      addNode(&(*tree)->leftChild, tok);
   }
   else if(tok > (*tree)->name)
   {
      addNode(&(*tree)->rightChild, tok);
   }

}
```

Comment: `if(tok < (*tree)->name)` looks fishy... `if(tok < *((*tree)->name))`, maybe?

Comment: maybe `char tok` --> `char *tok`, and change to use `strcmp` for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your member `name` is of type `char *`. Use `strcmp` instead of `<` and `>` and `char*` instead of `char`. Change your code to this:

```
void addNode(WordTreeNode ** tree, char * tok)
                                     // ^
{
    WordTreeNode *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = (WordTreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(WordTreeNode));
        temp->leftChild = temp->rightChild = NULL;

        temp->name = malloc( strlen(tok)+1 );
        strcpy( temp->name, tok );
        // don't forget to free the memory when youe destroy the node

        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }

    if( strcmp( tok, (*tree)->name) < 0 )
     // ^^^^^^
    {
        addNode(&(*tree)->leftChild, tok);
    }
    else if ( strcmp( tok, (*tree)->name) > 0 )
           // ^^^^^^
    {
        addNode(&(*tree)->rightChild, tok);
    }
}
```

Comment: The member name is of type char. Thank you!